# Problems with connecting bones to mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

Having this issue with combining bones to the mesh. Just set parent to the armature with automatic weights. Can someone tell me why those parts aren't connected to the mesh?  [image]

Comment: The armature's bones can only move vertices. If there aren't enough vertices to deform, the shapes will follow the bones. Show us a the screenshot in Wireframe Mode (Z).

Comment: I deleted this file. But that makes sense. So if I were to add a loop cut in the middle, would that work?

Comment: Yes, you will probabyl need more than one loop cut. Look at the examples on [this page](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Limb_Topology) and how the vertices are distributed in the elbow and knee are to give support for deformations. It is advisable to start rigging (and weighting) after finishing the topology work.

Comment: This is very very helpful, thank you so much for the information and links:D